# Python writing one character per cell

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm **scraping** a website for my work that basically have to search a list of numbers called 'cpf' (stored in Google Sheets) and then write the infos that the url will show, but now I'm having some troubles with the Sheet Update.

I'ts giving me one character per cell, do you have any ideas why this may be happening?

```
class CpfSearch(object):
def __init__(self, spreadsheet_name):
    self.cpf_col = 1
    self.nome_col = 2
    self.idade_col = 3
    self.beneficio_col = 4
    self.concessao_col = 5
    self.salario_col = 6
    self.consig_col = 9
    self.card_col = 15

    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('CONSULTAS.json', scope)

    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    self.sheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name).sheet1

def process_cpf_list(self):
    cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]

    bot_url = BOT(cpfs)
    nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()

    print("Atualizando...")
    for i in range(len(nomes)):
        self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.nome_col, nomes[i])
        self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.idade_col, idades[i])
        self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[i])
        self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[i])
        self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.salario_col, salarios[i])
        self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.consig_col, consigs[i])
        self.sheet.update_cell(i+2, self.card_col, cards[i])


cpf_updater = CpfSearch('TESTE')
cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
```

Here`s the search_cpfs()

```
    def search_cpfs(self):
    nomes = []
    idades = []
    beneficios = []
    concessoes = []
    salarios = []
    bancoss = []
    bancoscard = []
    consigs = []
    cards = []

    for cpf in self.cpfs:
        print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")

        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
        cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

        time.sleep(2)

        cpfButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
        cpfButton.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
        idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").text
        beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b").text
        concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").text
        salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
        consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
        card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

        nomes.append(nome)
        idades.append(idade)
        beneficios.append(beneficio)
        concessoes.append(concessao)
        salarios.append(salario)
        consigs.append(consig)
        cards.append(card)

        print(nome, idade, beneficio, concessao, salario, consig, card)

    return nome, idade, beneficio, concessao, salario, consig, card
```

Comment: could you post the code for search_cpfs()  it looks like it is returning strings not lists if you ` print(nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, consigs, cards)` it will confirm this or not

Comment: Thanks for your attention Dan, I`v posted the search_cpfs()

Comment: In search_cpfs() you are returning the strings nome, idade, beneficio, concessao, salario, consig, card.
Try returning the lists nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, consigs, cards.

Comment: thanks man, it worked like a charm! hugs from brazil

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer to make it more clear for others who could face this issue.
As [Dan-Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151578/python-writing-one-character-per-cell#comment108191914_61151578) said:

> In search_cpfs() you are returning the strings nome, idade, beneficio, concessao, salario, consig, card. Try returning the lists nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, consigs, cards